# Long running requests with gunicorn + nginx

Tags: nginx, django, gunicorn

I've put together an integration server for our Django-powered application. A few of the features are still experimental, and result in overly long requests.

I'm okay with the poor performance, for now, but I need to be able to integrate. Whenever we use the feature that leads to a long request, the app hangs (as expected) and then, after maybe a minute and a half, returns a '502 - Bad Gateway'. The rest of the app works fine.

I checked the gunicorn log, and whenever this happens I get a line like

```
2012-01-20 17:30:13 [23128] [DEBUG] GET /results/
2012-01-20 17:30:43 [23125] [ERROR] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:23128)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/demo/python_envs/frontend/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 111, in run
    os.setpgrp()
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

however, this happens long before the actual worker timeout, which I've set to 10 minutes just to make sure. Here's part of the upstart script that runs gunicorn.

```
description "..."

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
#Send KILL after 5 seconds
kill timeout 5
respawn

env VENV="/path/to/a/virtual/env/"

#how to know the pid
pid file $VENV/run/guniconr-8080.pid

script
exec sudo -u demo $VENV/bin/gunicorn_django --preload --daemon -w 4 -t 600 --log-level debug --log-file $VENV/run/gunicorn-8080.log -p $VENV/run/gunicorn-8080.pid -b localhost:8080 /path/to/settings.py
end script
```

I'm running gunicorn version 0.13.4. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

`502 Bad Gateway` means your gunicorn worker is timeout. You can add `--timeout` option to the `gnuicorn` command. The default is 30s.

As @greg-k notes, `proxy_read_timeout` option of Nginx controls yet another timeout. If you see `504 Gateway Timeout` error, you can adjust this option.

Comment: It's been a while since I've worried about this, but- isn't that the same at the `-t` option I already had in the question?

Answer (score 3):

This is maybe an issue with your nginx configuration.
Did you configure the proxy_read_timeout value?

> This directive sets the read timeout for the response of the proxied server. It determines how long nginx will wait to get the response to a request. The timeout is established not for entire response, but only between two operations of reading.

Source: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_read_timeout

Comment: I just moved to a larger/faster server for development ($$ :(), but if this comes up again I'll test your suggestion!